# Cross platform project automation

Tags: deployment, automation

The web shop where I work we do both .Net and PHP/Linux development. We'd like to start automating a lot more of our deployment processes using a common system that can be used for both. What would you recommend as a good common scripting language or automation system (like Ant or Maven) that works well for both .Net and Linux development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Maven, but we've managed to get Ant to do everything we've wanted on multiple platforms, just by virtue of the fact that you can extend it with any Java program to do special tasks not included with the Ant application itself.

And then Java can, if necessary, call any external program you want to by using Runtime.exec(). Loses a bit of the portability but it was required for some command-line tools under both Linux and Windows.

Comment: We where thinking of some Java tooling. We might look into CruiseControl which seems to work well for Linux environments and CruiseControl.NET for all Microsoft hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see how Perl does cross platform automation. The design for Perl6, seems to be a bit better designed, but the Perl5 design has had many years to develop.

Perl has been ported to many different platforms, not just Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You may get some mileage out of [Capistrano](http://capify.org/). It is rails centric but it is pretty general purpose, and I believe it has been extended to do other things also. Not sure how well it plays with Windows and .NET, but worth a look.

Comment: We don't really want to add another platform to both our current server environments. It probably also means we need to set up Apache web server on all windows boxes etc. We also don't want to learn Ruby. Ruby is out of the question.

Comment: platform? it's a tool same as anything you would use for this. also I don't think there is an apache dependency. fair enough if you don't want to learn ruby, but you're going to have to learn something :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can develop .net on linux using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).
On that linux server you can use both .net and php.

Comment: Yeah right. Our corporate clients (banks and insurance companies etc.) are going to run mono. Don't think so...

Comment: That's what they used to say about Linux :-)